# remap pane navigation shortcuts for tmux

Tags: tmux

I want to remap the shortcuts to switch between panes. By default it's `ctrl + b + arrow`. I'd like to set it up more like vim: `ctrl + b + hjkl`. Is it possible to do it by changing `~/.tmux`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having this in my config, and it works as comment tells:

```
#switch panels
bind k selectp -U # switch to panel Up
bind j selectp -D # switch to panel Down 
bind h selectp -L # switch to panel Left
bind l selectp -R # switch to panel Right
```